# Remove weatherforecast default route

Tags: asp.net-core

I have started a default .Net Core WebAPI project using the 3.0 preview 8. I have removed the default `weatherforecast` controller from the project, and added my own controller. However, starting the project always defaults to the route `https://localhost:44380/weatherforecast`. I can not find the setting to change this. How do I set the default controller in .Net Core 3?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, click the "Show all Files" button.

It will show the Properties pseudo-folder. In `launchSetting.json` the startup url is configured.

Comment: That solved it for me. I also have a docker-compose file in my solution, which had an override file hidden away that also had the weatherforecast route specified.

Answer (score 8):

You could also right click your project -> Select Properties -> Select the Debug tab on the left -> Then edit the 'Launch browser' field to set your own default launch url.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Applies for docker**
Since the OP has mentioned docker.
Just to append a bit to the answer.

> Changing the Launch settings is correct, although there is a case where it might not work.

> **I recently came upon this issue and even though my `launchsettings` were correct I was still directed to the `weatherforecast`route.**

The reason for this was in my `docker-compose.dcproj` the XML property `DockerServiceUrl`
was still pointing to the `{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/weatherforecast`. I needed to update the value there as well.

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2022, Project, Properties, Debug, then link: Open debug lauch profile. Set the Url as u like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    On Visual Studio for Mac
Right click your Project -> Select Options -> 
Select Run -> Configurations -> Default tab on the left -> 
Select Asp.Net Core Tab -> unselect Open URL in web browser when app starts checkbox
```

[image: .net core app disable start page]